# PHP require & header effect calling file when in external file function

Tags: php, header, require

So an example of what I want to do.

main.php

```
<?php
    require_once("setup.php")
    setup();
?>
```

setup.php

```
<?php
    function setup() {
        require_once("other.php") // Requires this file in main.php not setup.php
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); // This header to also effect main.php not setup.php
    }
?>
```

other.php

```
<?php
    // Stuff that main.php needs but must be part of the setup function
?>
```

Comment: And the problem lies in .....?

Comment: Sounds like a plan, Stan. Give it a whirl, and if you have any issues make sure to come back and ask a question.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, the functions inside other.php can't seem to be called from main.php

Comment: doing the require inside the function means that any vars that `other.php` defines will be defined in the scope of that function, and lost when the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

Changing everything from *require_once* to *require* seems to have fixed it all.